# How to send PayPal invoice using PayPal REST API and PayPal Developer Live Account, in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am developing a desktop app, which will use PayPal's REST API to create and send the Invoices to batches, using Python. I used [paypalrestsdk](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/tree/master) to create the Invoice using the credentials (Client ID and Client Secret) from Live Account (Not Sandbox), but when I use the `send()` method to send the Invoices, my app just keeps on loading and in the PayPal Developers API Calls interface, I see I am getting 401 error which is a Permission Error.

Well, I thought that as the library is deprecated, so why not create my own method to send the Invoices. So, below is the mixture of `paypalrestsdk` library to create invoice and my own code to send invoice using `request` library:

```
def send_invoices_batch(self, email_list):
        paypalrestsdk.configure({
            "mode": "live", # sandbox or live
            "client_id": str(self.clientIdInput.text()),
            "client_secret": str(self.clientSecretInput.text())
        })

        invoices = []  # Store Invoice objects for each email

        # Construct and store Invoice objects for each email
        # for email in email_list:
        invoice = self.construct_invoice(email_list)
        invoices.append(invoice)

        # Create and send invoices using the paypalrestsdk library
        for invoice in invoices:
            invoice_created = invoice.create()
            if invoice_created:
                print("INVOICE CREATED:", invoice_created)
                self.responseDisplay.append(f"Invoice {invoice.id} created successfully!")
            else:
                self.responseDisplay.append(f"Failed to create invoice {invoice.id}: {invoice.error}")

            paypalrestsdk.configure({
                "mode": "live", # sandbox or live
                "client_id": str(self.clientIdInput.text()),
                "client_secret": str(self.clientSecretInput.text())
            })

            send_url = f"https://api.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/{invoice.id}/send"
            headers = {
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.get_access_token()}",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
            response = requests.post(send_url, headers=headers)

            if response.status_code == 202:
                self.responseDisplay.append(f"Invoice {invoice.id} sent successfully!")
            else:
                self.responseDisplay.append(f"Failed to send invoice {invoice.id}: {response.text}")

def get_access_token(self):
        auth_url = "https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"
        headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Accept-Language": "en_US"
        }
        data = {
            "grant_type": "client_credentials"
        }
        auth = (self.clientIdInput.text(), self.clientSecretInput.text())
        
        response = requests.post(auth_url, headers=headers, data=data, auth=auth)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            access_token = response.json().get("access_token")
            return access_token
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Failed to obtain access token: {response.text}")
```

When I run my app now and try to create and send the Invoices, at the sending step, I get the following error in my app:

Failed to send invoice [INVOICE-ID]: {"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","message":"Authorization error occurred.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#errors","debug_id":"48832993cf8a2"}

Some facts about my app and PayPal Account:

- I am using Live Account Credentials (Client ID and Client Secret)
- I have confirmed that the account has the permission to create and send Invoice
- I am sending a POST request and not the GET request to the Sneding Invoice API

Can anyone see and let me know what is wrong I am doing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That SDK is deprecated, do not use it for any purpose

The v1/invoicing API is also deprecated, do not use it for any purpose

The current version of the PayPal Invoicing API [is documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/integrate/). Use only it.

Comment: @PrestonPPHX If the SDK is deprecated, then how do I create and send PayPal Invoices in Python? The documentation just provides help for other languages and not Python.

Comment: Is there any working example of new API in Python? Or I will have to write all code on my own?